# Expand [kingdom-hearts-unchainedx] to [kingdom-hearts-unchained-x]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

A relic from the old 25-characters limit, the [kingdom-hearts-unchainedx](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdom-hearts-unchainedx) tag should be expanded to make use of the new limit.

Comment: Is there anything that prohibits you (or anyone else) retagging the only 3 tagged questions?

Comment: Tags with different spacing are not recognized by the system as being distinct. I can't create the correct tag as long as the old one exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done :)

[kingdom-hearts-unchainedx](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdom-hearts-unchainedx) -> [kingdom-hearts-unchained-x](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdom-hearts-unchained-x)